# Android spinner onselecteditem spinner is null?

Tags: java, android, null, spinner, android-sdk-tools

below find all my code and xml. My problem is that the spinner (in code spinner1) is null for some reason I can't determine and I get no errors other than the app failing to run. Any help would be appreciated!

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.passwordplayground;

import java.util.Locale;

import com.example.MyApplication.EncryptionSpinner;
import com.example.MyApplication.MyApplication;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.encryptionSpin);
        if (spinner1 == null)
            System.out.println("Spinner1 is null");
        else
            System.out.println("Funcion is null");
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new EncryptionSpinner());

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return ("Practicality").toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = null;
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.encryption,container, false);
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                        container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText("I'm second!");
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==3) {
                //dummyTextView.setText("I'm third");
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==4) {
                //dummyTextView.setText("I'm fourth and last!");
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

encryption.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$Encryption" >

    <Spinner
        android1:id="@+id/encryptionSpin"
        android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android1:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android1:background="@color/orange"
        android1:entries="@array/cryptArray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EncryptionSpinner.java:

```
package com.example.MyApplication;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class EncryptionSpinner implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        System.out.println(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
04-09 01:16:28.637: I/System.out(1440): Spinner1 is null
04-09 01:16:28.657: D/AndroidRuntime(1440): Shutting down VM
04-09 01:16:28.657: W/dalvikvm(1440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.passwordplayground/com.example.passwordplayground.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.example.passwordplayground.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-09 01:16:28.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     ... 11 more
```

Layouts' Gui:
[image: layouta_main vs encryption]

Comment: you are not assign any values to spinner..

Comment: or its not matching id with layout file.

Comment: have you tried `view.getContext()` instead of `MyApplication.getAppContext()` ?

Comment: @Achilles, does this Spinner spinner1 = not assign a value?

Comment: Please post your logcat error. @Kyle

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, yes I have and it still prints that it is null and it crashes.

Comment: @GrIsHu it has been posted.

Comment: @Kyle In which layout your `ViewPager` view is ?

Comment: I know its in the mainactivity.java with the fragments. Its for the different tab layout I'm doing.

Comment: @Kyle You putting ViewPager in activity_mail layout and Spinner in encryption.xml if u setting content view as any one of xml. so any one ll identify another one will not be identify. It will through the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to user spinner from activity_main then you have to put it in that file because right now its not their and it is in encryption.xml file.

make activity_main.xml like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$Encryption" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 

    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <Spinner
        android1:id="@+id/encryptionSpin"
        android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android1:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android1:background="@color/orange"
        android1:entries="@array/cryptArray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but the variable itself is still null.

Comment: you have also activity_main xml file?

Comment: Yes I do, my question has been updated to include it.\

Comment: then put your activity_main xml file also.

Comment: I understand the answer, but, it is in my encryption.xml layout because of my tabs. Its in that layout.

Comment: buddy you are try to access spinner from other xml file which not possible without this.. make it clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have inflated the layout `activity_main` in your activity and you are trying to access the `Spinner` which is not in your `activity_main` layout.

In that point you are getting error. As the `Spinner` does not resides in your `activity_main` layout.

So will have to initialize your `Spinner` in `DummySectionFragment` `onCreateView` method as below:

```
 public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.encryption,container, false);
              Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.encryptionSpin);
        }
```

Comment: If I changed the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in the onCreate function to setContentView(R.layout.encryption); would that fix the problem. Although according to my fragment tab code, it should go there anyway as it is infalted during loading of tab1.

Comment: Ok I've added the code you suggested and now I'm getting a null pointer on line 68: mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter); so my guess is it doesn't like something that was added to that function.

Answer (score 0):

you see there is null pointer exception.
means you have no control on the components you are using.
this could be caused due to two reason
 1. two components have same ids.
 2. wrong defined layout.

in your case you are using layout

```
R.layout.activity_main
```

while your layout name is

```
R.layout.encryption
```

change the name of layout and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have now changed it to setContentView(R.layout.encryption);. But unfortunately I still received the error leaving it where it was in onCreate. Some one else suggested moving it to the fragment, which I did but caused another null error on a different line.

Answer (score 0):

You putting ViewPager in activity_mail layout and Spinner in encryption.xml if u setting content view as any one of xml. so any one ll identify another one will not be identify. It will throw the null pointer exception.

R.layout.activity_main having ViewPager

R.layout.encryption having Spinner

if u set `setcontentView(R.layout.activity_main)` then  `findViewById(R.id.encryptionSpin);` line will throw null pointer.

if u set `setcontentView(R.layout.encryption)` then  `mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);` line will throw null pointer.

Comment: @Kyle put both Views in one xml and set that xml in setContentView()

Comment: I can't though (at least don't know how) as one is the default layout which calls the layout that contains the different tabs. It was auto generated by the sdk itself during project creation.

Comment: @Kyle can u post the graphical representation of your layout/View

Comment: it has been done. The second gui is the gui that is loaded into the first tab.

Comment: @Kyle So First Screen you have 4 Action Tabs and in Ist tab you need to load Spinner right?

Comment: @Yubaraja Yes that is correct, the activity_main layout is what is loaded first. This contains the tabs which in the first initial(default) tab there is the spinner. The tutorials I followed suggested that each tab be its own layout. So that is what I have done and that is why it is inside the encryption.xml layout. Which is what is told be inflated inside the MainActivity.java